# Get url path from guzzleHttp requestAsync after setup

Tags: php, url, guzzle

I've a problem using guzzleHttp with multiple requests. I want to get the path of an url after setup the request but before sending it. Here's my code:

```
include "../../vendor/autoload.php";

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

/* Initiate Guzzle Client */
$client = new Client([
    "verify" => false, // disable ssl certificate verification
    "timeout" => 30, // maximum timeout for requests
    "http_errors" => false, // disable exceptions
    ]);

$requests      = [];
$requests["a"] = $client->requestAsync('GET', "https://www.aaa.de/aaa.html");
$requests["b"] = $client->requestAsync('GET', "https://www.bbb.de/bbb.html");
$requests["c"] = $client->requestAsync('GET', "https://www.ccc.de/ccc.html");

$content = performMultiRequest($requests);

function performMultiRequest($requests)
{

    foreach ($requests as $key => $object) {
        print_r($object);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * here comes more to send the requests, but that doesn't care for this problem
     */
}
```

In this case I get a **GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise** Object. My goal is to get only the path **/aaa.html** from `$object`. It must be found inside the function `performMultiRequest()`. There's no chance to read and parse the url before, e.g. when the `requestAsync()` is used.

This is the relevant part of `$object` I need:

[image]

I tried SO, Guzzle documentation, google, trail & error... nothing found... any ideas?

Comment: If you can access the request, then based on the PSR7 interface you can: `$object->request->getUri()->getPath()` ?

Comment: @zanderwar I tried this already - this delivers an error: `Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::$request`

Comment: The only context promises have is the \Closure it was given when it was created, all of which is hidden behind private properties (in this case, behind waitFn and cancelFn of the Promise class). You can use Reflection to access these private properties, but sadly guzzle jacks it full of nested promises so actually getting that far down to finally extract the path before it gets sent will result in some very ugly code, I spent a little while trying to make this work for you but your sanest option here is to change approach. Good luck

Comment: if you are doing this just to get the path why don't use just use the basename method? it will give everything after the last / i.e. basename("https://www.aaa.de/aaa.html")  this will give you aaa.html

Comment: @codenathan unfortunatelly I need the url **inside** the `performMultiRequest()`... otherweise it's very simple to use `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)`

Comment: @zanderwar you're right - i tried this way, too... but theres no chance to get the private properties. And there are no methods to receive the informations from these properties ...